# License for StackOverflow Blog content

Tags: support, blog, licensing, content

The footer on the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) mentions a [BY-NC-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/) for the *podcasts*, but doesn't mention the text on the blog itself. I'm asking because, as a StackExchange user, I find lots of content there very inspiring and would like to "borrow" (translate) some of it for my own Q&A community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fine, as long as you provide a link back (citation) to the original source.

Comment: Does this mean that you've now granted explicit permission to everyone who reads this answer under those conditions or only the OP?